# Shader Management for Lighting?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am currently learning to apply more materials with lighting to my application, but then I got confused on how I should scale it. I'm using WebGL and I'm learning from learningwebgl.com (which they say the same as NeHe OpenGL tutorial), and it only shows simple shader programs that every sample have one program with embedded lighting on it.

Say I have multiple lighting setup, like some point lights/spot lights, and I have multiple meshes with different materials, but every mesh need to react with those lights. What should I do? make individual shader programs where you put colors/textures to meshes and then switch to lighting program? or always have every shader strings in my application with those lights (as functions) as default in it, append it to loaded shaders, and simply make variable passes to enable them?

Also I am focusing on per-fragment lighting, so maybe things only happen in fragment shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally 2 approches

1. Have an uber shader

   In this case you make a big shader with every option possible and lots of branching or ways to effectively nullify parts of the shader (like multiplying with 0)

   A simple example might be to have an array of lights uniforms in the shader. For lights you don't want to have an effect you just set their color 0,0,0,0 or their power to 0 so they are still calculated but they contribute nothing to the final scene.
2. Generate shaders on the fly

   In this case for each model you figure out what options you need for that shader and generate the appropriate shader with the exact features you need.

   A variation of #2 is the same but all the various shaders needed are generated offline.

Most game engines use technique #2 as it's far more efficient to use the smallest shader possible for each situation than to run an uber shader but many smaller projects and even game prototypes often use an uber shader because it's easier then generating shaders. Especially if you don't know all the options you'll need yet.

Comment: You could mix the two approaches too perhaps?
Have a selection of a few shaders to handle the different styles, and each one has parameters?